# Comet with ASP.NET AsyncHttpHandlers

Tags: asp.net, .net, comet, ihttpasynchandler

I am implementing a comet using AsyncHttpHandlers in my current asp.net application. According to my implementation client initially sends Notification Hook request to server (with its user id) on AsyncHttpHandler, and on server side I maintain a Global (Application level) dictionary of userid(key) and IAynsResult (value). So when ever a request is received to send notification to a user I just pick the matching IAsyncResult from the Global Dictionary and send response to the client user.

My concern is, is maintaing a Dictionary of Userid and IAsyncResult at  Application level a good design? I feel it will put a lot of load on the server, at the time of high traffic.
Is there any other way I can achieve the comet. or what will be the good design to achieve comet for high traffic scenarios.

Comment: You should check PokeIn library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the number of requests to the server, IAsyncResult request utilizes the process's `ThreadPool` which automatically manages the number of worker threads. These threads are assigned a task, run them to completion, then are returned to the ThreadPool for reuse.

The ThreadPool is used by other aspects of .NET, and provides a **limited** number of threads. If you overuse it, there is the possibility your tasks will be blocked waiting for others to complete!

So basically, running a comet server on an ASP.net needs either a strong hardware, or application distribution over several servers.

I would recommend [HTML5 WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which is the [W3C API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) for implementing sockets in HTML and is easier to setup on an ASP.net server:

[SignalR for .net 4](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

[ASP.net WebSocket API for .net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.websockets.aspnetwebsocket.aspx)

Comment: is it possible to create a video chat server using HTML5 Websockets ??

Comment: No, it's not! The streaming part is OK,however you can not render video streamed in such a way: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/browse_thread/thread/bec3ac48af5766b1?pli=1

Comment: thanks for the reply, i only want to implement streaming part using websockets.